# Java cannot find symbol class Random

Tags: java

I had this line in my source code `import java.util.Random;`
The IDE told me that `util` does not contain `Random`.
When I press Alt + Enter, the IDE recommended me to create class `Random` in `java.util`.
When I was typing `java.util.` and press Ctrl + Space, it took very long time to "scan classpath", then, Random was not be listed.

How can I import the `Random` class in my project. My project is set to use java8. 
Thank you for reading my question. Is the problem the IDE?

Comment: add in what IDE you are using

Comment: What IDE are you using, and is it aware of where your JDK lives?

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, you want to open project properties, and select your current SDK.

Find the image at the bottom of this page.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html

Comment: Sorry for late response, my IDE is NetBeans 8.2. And the problem is not come from the IDE. I use exactly the same IDE at new installed system, work fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem is my HDD was corrupted. I had reinstalled entire my system (include the java jdk) at new location. My IDE had already been installed at that new location, so I re-use it (no re-install the IDE) and work fine. I'm think the problem is the java libraries was corrupted because of my HDD.